# pactl not working in DWM config file

Tags: audio, keyboard-shortcuts, pulseaudio, dwm

After seting up shortcuts in config.h, pactl is not working at all. However when I run pactl in terminal, it works as intended

config.h:

```
#include <X11/XF86keysym.h>

static const char *upvol[]   = { "/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-volume", "@DEFAULT_SINK@", "+5%",     NULL };
static const char *downvol[] = { "/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-volume", "@DEFAULT_SINK@", "-5%",     NULL };
static const char *mutevol[] = { "/usr/bin/pactl", "set-sink-mute",   "@DEFAULT_SINK@", "toggle",  NULL };

static Key keys[] = {
    { 0,                       XF86XK_AudioLowerVolume, spawn, {.v = downvol } },
    { 0,                       XF86XK_AudioMute, spawn, {.v = mutevol } },
    { 0,                       XF86XK_AudioRaiseVolume, spawn, {.v = upvol   } }

};
```

Even if i replace `@DEFAULT_SINK@` with `1` (which is my current sink), it still dosen't work

function keys work because xev detects that they have assigned events:

```
KeymapNotify event, serial 37, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  2   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
```

I run DWM through LightDM session with dwm.desktop file in /usr/share/xsessions:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Encoding=UTF-8
Name=dwm
Comment=Dynamic window manager
Exec=dwm
Icon=dwm
Type=XSession
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out DWM in some cases must be fully reinstalled to overwrite some settings

```
sudo make uninstall && sudo make install
```